# AJAX post request will not send JSON data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, ashx

After banging my head against the wall over this for the past few hours trying to debug this, I have finally resolved to asking for help.

I have this data like this I am wanting to send to an ashx handler (it's a good deal of data).

```
var value = [{"start":["3,0"],"block":["0,0","1,2"],"end":["2,1"],"star":"gold","moves":3,"difficulty":"easy"},{"start":["1,0"],"block":["1,3","3,0","4,2"],"end":["0,1"],"star":"gold","moves":4,"difficulty":"easy"},{"start":["3,0"],"block":["0,0","0,2","2,0","3,2"],"end":["1,0"],"star":"silver","moves":4,"difficulty":"easy"},{"start":["3,0"],"block":["0,0","2,0","3,1"],"end":["1,3"],"star":"gold","moves":6,"difficulty":"easy"},{"start":["0,0","2,0"],"block":["2,3"],"end":["1,2"],"star":"gold","moves":4,"difficulty":"easy"},{"start":["2,1"],"block":["0,1","0,2","1,0","1,1","2,0","2,2","2,3","3,1","3,2"],"end":["1,3"],"star":"gold","moves":5,"difficulty":"easy"},{"start":["1,0"],"block":["0,0","3,0","2,3"],"end":["4,1"],"star":"gold","moves":5,"difficulty":"medium"},{"start":["0,0","0,4"],"block":["0,5","0,2","3,3"],"end":["1,1"],"star":"gold","moves":7,"difficulty":"medium"},{"start":["0,0","2,6"],"block":["0,5","3,3","2,1"],"end":["3,5"],"star":"gold","moves":8,"difficulty":"medium"},{"start":["4,1","4,3"],"block":["3,0","4,2"],"end":["0,1","1,4","3,2"],"star":"gold","moves":8,"difficulty":"medium"},{"start":["1,2","3,4","4,2"],"block":["0,2","3,0"],"end":["2,3"],"star":"gold","moves":9,"difficulty":"medium"},{"start":["3,1","3,6"],"block":["0,0","0,3","0,7","2,5"],"end":["2,3"],"star":"gold","moves":11,"difficulty":"hard"},{"start":["0,7","0,2"],"block":["2,0","3,2","0,6","1,6","1,7"],"end":["3,3"],"star":"gold","moves":12,"difficulty":"hard"},{"start":["0,0","0,3"],"block":["0,1","2,2","3,0","3,3"],"end":["4,2"],"star":"gold","moves":8,"difficulty":"hard"},{"start":["0,0","0,6"],"block":["0,1","1,0","1,1","2,5","3,7"],"end":["3,4"],"star":"gold","moves":13,"difficulty":"hard"},{"start":["0,0","0,2","0,4","2,0","2,4","3,2","4,0","4,4"],"block":["0,1","0,3","1,0","1,1","1,2","1,3","1,4","2,1","2,3","3,0","3,1","3,3","3,4","4,1","4,2","4,3"],"end":["2,2"]},{"start":["0,0","0,2","0,4","1,1","2,0","2,4","3,2","4,0","4,2","4,4"],"block":["0,1","0,3","1,0","1,2","1,3","1,4","2,1","2,3","3,0","3,1","3,3","3,4","4,1","4,3"],"end":["2,2"],"star":"silver","moves":42,"difficulty":"medium"},{"start":["0,0","3,3","4,0"],"block":["0,1","2,3","3,0","4,4"],"end":["0,3"],"star":"gold","moves":11,"difficulty":"hard"},{"start":["0,4","1,1","3,5","4,2"],"block":["0,0","3,1","4,1"],"end":["2,3"],"star":"gold","moves":14,"difficulty":"hard"},{"start":["0,0","3,2","3,6"],"block":["0,4","0,5","4,4"],"end":["1,1"],"star":"gold","moves":13,"difficulty":"hard"},{"start":["0,2"],"block":["0,7","4,0","4,6","5,0","6,0","6,5"],"end":["2,0"]}]
```

And I am using this function to send the request:

```
function storeValue(value) {
    var val = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(value));
    $.ajax({
        url: "DataHandler.ashx",
        async: false,
        data: { key: "someKey", value: val, action: "store" },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
};
```

In the DataHandler.ashx, this is the relevant code:

```
public class DataHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
             var query = context.Request.QueryString;
             string action = query["action"];
             string key = query["key"];
             string val = query["value"];
        }
    }
```

Through debugging, I find out that the DataHander isn't even being called. If I remove the `value` from the query string, like this:

```
data: { key: key, action: "store" },
```

The ProcessRequest method will be called as I would expect.

I am guessing that `value` might be too long or something. Why isn't it being sent, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring your request via Fiddler or Firebug?  Also, having this be a GET will probably cause you to run into the max length of a URI + query string, which I think is in the 2000-4000 char limit.  I think IE8 has a 2048 limit.  If you run your request through Fiddler, do you see it being sent out?  If so, what error (if any) do you see in the response?

Comment: Why you didn't add `type: "POST"` in `$.ajax`? Other way, i think it does GET request, and data has to be given in one string like this: `var=val&var2=val2` and so on...

Comment: @David It has a `400 Bad Request` error.

Comment: Try changing the method to POST and see what happens.  If this works, you are probably hitting the GET length limit.

Comment: @David Changing to POST and changing `context.Request.QueryString` to `context.Request.Form` fixed it, thanks. Can you post an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run my test code, I see the following error come back from the jQuery ajax call:

> **Exception Details**: System.Web.HttpException: The length
>   of the query string for this request
>   exceeds the configured
>   maxQueryStringLength value.

So your query string is too long (at least for IE9 which is what I'm testing on).

As the comments suggested, changing this to a POST allows the ProcessRequest method to be reached in your ASHX file.

You'd also want to change ProcessRequest to retrieve values from the request body, not the query string....

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var query = context.Request;
    string action = query["action"];
    string key = query["key"];
    string val = query["value"];
}
```

I hope this helps!